# Interpretation of $(2,0)$-tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, tensor-rank

I am aware that $(0,2)$-tensors are things like an inner product, a differential $2$-form, and more generally a bilinear map. I am aware that $(1,1)$-tensors are just linear endomorphisms. But what about $(2,0)$-tensors? They are elements of the space $V \otimes V$ so it is not correct to think of them as pairs of vectors, and simply saying they are "formal sums of pairs of vectors modulo some relations" is nothing more than citing the definition. Hence my question to complete the triad of rank-$2$ tensors: is there a nice interpretation of $(2,0)$-tensors?

Comment: You can evaluate bilinear forms on them, so you do have a duality statement. Is that not good enough? They are very much the same as bilinear forms for finite dimensional spaces

Comment: @Pedro I was thinking that maybe you could think of them as formal sums of oriented parallelograms, but I thought that maybe there was a better description. I know that it is a vague question, but I'm looking for what they "are" instead of what we are "allowed to do with them" if that makes sense.

Comment: @EduardodeLorenzo You cannot think of them as formal sums of oriented parallelograms. That would be the exterior algebra $\bigwedge^2 V$, where the relation $v \wedge w = -w \wedge v$ is satisfied. In the tensor product, $v \otimes w$ and $w \otimes v$ are completely distinct.

Comment: In the most abstract sense, a $(p,q)$ tensor takes $p$ vectors and $q$ covectors and tells you what to do with them, with the restriction that they act bilinearly and transform like tensors. So how you interpret any tensor intuitively depends strongly on what kind of vectors/covectors you have. As Pedro says, there is a duality - $(2,0)$ vs $(0,2)$ tensors are both vector 'products', or 2-forms, or bilinear maps, etc... and differ in exactly the sense the vectors differ from the covectors.